# How switch activity from non-activity StateMachine?

Tags: android, class, android-activity, switch-statement, state-machine

## Problem:

> I've written State Machine for my android application. It is separate class, extension of Android 4.0.3 StateMachine. And I want this SM could switch activities.
> Is it possible to implement?
>   I mean that such thing as
>
> `startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class))`
>
> was called not from current activity but inside my state machine.
>   Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

## My solution:

#### (special thanks to @Jan-Henk)

Inside my CurrentActivity call
    `stateMachine.sendMessage(SM.MSG_SWITCH_ACTIVITY, CurrentActivity.this);`
and inside my State put next code:

```
@Override
public void exit()
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // necessary to avoid exceptions
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean processMessage(final Message message)
{
    boolean returnedValue;
    switch(message.what)
    {
        case MSG_SWITCH_ACTIVITY:
            //sendMessage(obtainMessage(MSG_SWITCH_ACTIVITY));
            context = (Context) message.obj; // context - it's a field of my state machine
            transitionTo(nextActivity);
            returnedValue = HANDLED;
        break;
        default:
            returnedValue = NOT_HANDLED;
        break;
    }           
    return returnedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `startActivity` from a Context object, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent).

Comment: This is right and I would add that your state machine needs reference to a valid context.  So use composition, set a context or you could use static methods perhaps, but using a context is key.

Comment: Hm... As far as I understood I can include some `Context ctx` into my SM and call `ctx.startActivity(intent)`. Ok, but the first parameter of this `intent` should be activity's context? How to pass it or get it? And how initialize `ctx`, because I'm tired of NullPointerExceptions :) I'm using StateMachine class from Android 4.0.3.

Comment: As Code Droid says, you need a referenced to a valid context. Then you can simply do `ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, NextActivity.class));`

Answer (score 0):

To call a next activity you can simply setup a new intent and call start activity as Jan-henk mentioned

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yoursecondclass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not appropriate.